# Ways to parse Json recursive

Tags: c#, json, parsing

My problem is that I need to parse json to another json format, I need to do that recursive. I have been tried diferents way but any works fine for me.
I would like to know more ways for test.
Thanks!

```
    {
  "items": {
    "itemName": {
      "type": "type",
      "properties": {
        "item1": {
          "type": 1,
          "isValid": true
        },
        "item2": {
          "type": 1,
          "isValid": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I need to make this

```
{
    "items":{
        "item1": 1,
        "item2": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some data, example and code

Comment: what even is "another" json format?

Comment: 1. use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) to parse to `dynamic` or a concrete class that matches the input format 2. copy the data from the input format to the new class format.

Comment: `I have been tried diferents way`  Why don't you share your attempts at solving this?  We can help you get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `JToken` to read the `JSON` and `JsonConvert` to convert the object to desired JSON

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    var inputString = r.ReadToEnd();
    JToken outer = JToken.Parse(inputString);
    JObject inner = outer["items"]["itemName"]["properties"].Value<JObject>();

    List<string> keys = inner.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    var items = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

    foreach (string k in keys)
    {
        items.Add(k, Convert.ToInt32(outer["items"]["itemName"]["properties"][k]["type"]));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { items = items }));
}
```

output

```
{"items":{"item1":1,"item2":2}}
```